# Restful Webservice does not answer

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to web service programming and running in trouble. After searching the web for two days i am totally confused and my example does not provide any data to me.

I want to write a restful web service that should run on tomcat 7 or glassfish 4.

Here my code:

**SimpleService.class**

```
@Path("say")
public class SimpleService {

    @Path("hello")
    @GET
    public String doGreet() {
        return "Hello Stranger, the time is "+ new Date();
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>test002</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/you/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The request on http.//localhost:8070/test002/you/say/hello gets an 404.

Comment: You map your Service on <url-pattern>/you/*</url-pattern> but you try to call it on rest. change this please.

Comment: It seems your URL mapping is wrong.. You have mapped jersey servlet to /you/* pattern

Comment: Sorry for this typo. I called localhost:8070/test002/you/say/hello and got a 404. Edited the question.

Comment: Do you see any errors in server logs when you start this application?

Comment: Here is something: SimpleService does not implement the javax.xml.ws.Provider interface - what does it mean? as in some documentation the Provider Interface is optional.

Comment: First step: check if your Jersey servlet is up (and OK). What does http://youhost:8070/test002/you/application.wadl give? Secondly, for JAX-RS you don't need the @WebServiceProvider

Comment: @Friso: I do not get an xml-output loading your url. the logfile tells:  Loading application [test002] at [/test002]]] and then: test002 wurde erfolgreich bereitgestellt in 297 Millisekunden.]] That all with removed WebServiceProvider. (updated the Question)

Comment: Following the sugestion to try it in tomcat i found out that eclipse was not able to find javax.ws.rs.Path and javax.ws.rs.GET. So now i downloaded (very slowly) the jee-sdk from oracle, installed it and nothing changes. Where do i get there libs from? What do i have to put into the build path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's wisest to start with a clean slate: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html If Maven is not an option, create the Maven project anyway and load it in Eclipse. Than copy the classpath settings and "maven dependencies" to your own project.

If you figure out where you went wrong, maybe post it here, so others can benefit.

Comment: Well, i guess my problem was, that i did not reload/restart the server after deploying a new version for testing. I switched to jboss, because it brings all libs i need and in the meantime i managed to bring my project up and running using maven. Cool stuff ;) So thanks for everyone's help. It is now running!

Answer (score 1):

My advise. Deploy your application on Tomcat and check if your application is running using the Tomcat manager application.

Make sure you use the EXACT name of your WAR file in your URL path:

```
http://localhost:8070/<Name of WAR-file>/you/say/hello
```

Also notice that tomcat uses port 8080 by default.

For Tomcat you'll also have to change your servlet-class definition in your web.xml.
Right now you are using the one of Glassfish. Maybe you can consider using Jersey since it is the JAX-RS reference implementation from Oracle.

In this case you have to specify

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

as your servlet-class.

Remove the `you` from your url-pattern and from the URL you use.

It's not a bad habit either to annotate your service method with the data you return, in your case it is plain text:

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

Your SimpleService doesn't need to implement an interface. It looks correct.

If it's working for Tomcat it won't be so hard to make it work for Glassfish...

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the full resource path in the service:

*SimpleService.class*

```
@Path("/you/say")
public class SimpleService {

    @Path("/hello")
    @GET
    public String doGreet() {
        return "Hello Stranger, the time is "+ new Date();
    }
}
```